# Add gaps between rows and columns in bootsrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

How to add gaps between rows and cols in bootstrap wihout breaking it. I want three column on each row so I have given `col-4` but when I add gap or margin it breaks.

I want it like this
[image]

but when I add margin or gaps it breaks like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `Gutters` in bootstrap to address the gaps issues between columns.

```
Gutters
Gutters are the padding between your columns, used to responsively space and align content in the Bootstrap grid system.
```

[Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/)